# Android countdown timer for a game

Tags: android

ok heres the problem im have i have made a fully working game, with menu and help page score lives levels, but i can't get the timer working as it should, at 1st i thought it was an if() but i ran it it would go down to fast.

i have made the game in using android java (eclipse), i would post some code up but im not sure which bits you would like to see, i now  that secs in java are milisecs so 50000/1000 = 50secs but i dont know how to do it, i looked a few exmaple code and im not sure how it is working.

the timer is a label i made that appear on the AVD, atm it just says 50000 and not doing anything

i tried doing it this way

public class timer extends CountDownTimer{

```
        public timer(long timer, long Interval) {

            super(timer, Interval);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //canvas.drawText("GAME OVER", 200, 700, paint);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            realtime = (int) millisUntilFinished;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: *i now that secs in java are milisecs* I'm sorry, what?

Comment: sorry about the grammer, my keybroad is kinda old and crap, some keys work the time,

Comment: if(timer = 50; timer < 0; timer--){ }

Comment: i mean >* in side the if()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the game starts save the system time and create a new Paint instance with the text size and color you want.

```
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    text = new Paint();
    text.setColor(Color.RED);
    text.setTextSize(20);
```

To draw the text onto the canvas / screen inside your onDrow method do something like this.

```
    timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long timeToGo = 50 - (timeNow - startTime) / 1000;
    if (timeToGo >= 0) {
        canvas.drawText(Long.toString(timeToGo), 10, 25, text);
    }
```

This will place a red count down timer in the top left of your screen that counts down from 50.

Comment: ok, but i need it to count back from 50 and to extacly to show it on screen, 50,49,48 ect, and all this will be on surface view using a canvas, not using any XML layout for the game itself, just hard coding

Comment: Knowing how to get the system time (System.currentTimeMillis) and working out how much elapsed time (timeNow -startTime) has passed is the basis of the code. Time is in milli seconds so you need to divide by 1000 and to work out how much time is left you just subtract how many seconds have passed from 50. Lastly is just a matter of drawing that text on the canvas, this has to be done in the onDraw method and requires a Paint instance to set the color and text size. Lastly you need to know how to convert time (a int) to a String in the drawText call.

Comment: thanks that help alot, inside the if(timeToGo <= 0){ timeToGo = 0; } would that stop it going intp minus numbers or no?

Comment: Just change the condition to be >= 0 and move the drawText call inside the conditional.
    if (timeToGo >= 0) {
        canvas.drawText(Long.toString(timeToGo), 10, 25, text);
    }

Comment: ok will do, how would i reset the timer back to 50 as the game has levels and each level give the player 50s to do?

Comment: To reset time just use startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

Comment: sorry to ask you again, is there a way to pause the timer?